# Intellisense doesn't work when I import the module from a cdn. vscode

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, three.js, autocomplete, cdn

I was importing three js this way:

```
import { WebGLRenderer } from 'three';
```

and the auto complete works fine (image 1).

But when I import from a cdn:

```
import { WebGLRenderer } from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/three';
```

The auto complete doesnt works (image 2)

image 1:
[image: image 1]

image 2:
[image: image 2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you'll need to install `@types/three`.
Then you can use `jsconfig.json` to alias `https://cdn.skypack.dev/*` to `@types/*`, because this way vscode / typescript knows how to interpret these urls.

`jsconfig.json`:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "https://cdn.skypack.dev/*": ["./node_modules/@types/*"]
        }
    }
}
```

More about this: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#paths

Comment: still dont working, [image](https://prnt.sc/84_54PrwDvOe).
EDIT: yes, I installed typings: `npm install typings --global`

Comment: You need to install `@types/three` locally. Therefore: `npm i @types/three -D`

Comment: @lusc This is a good one but is there a better way to do it in a static project? i.e. with a normal HTML, CSS and JS project? Without `npm`?

Comment: What if this was a vanilla javascript project with no node, npm, webpack, babel etc.
How can we acceess the types in this case?